XOR sum of array
When you are given an array of even number of elements:
[$a_1$ $a_2$ $a_3$ ….. $a_n$] ($n$ is even)
Assume the $a_i$ are not all zero
Let $S$ = the XOR sum of all these original elements
You will always be able to remove an element such that the XOR sum of the resulting array is non-zero
If you remove some element $a_i$, the XOR sum of the resulting array is
“S XOR $a_i$”. And there is always an $a_i$ such that “S XOR $a_i$” will never be zero. Why? Can someone help me understand the logic behind it?

This is false if the $a_i$ are all $0$

$\newcommand{\xor}[0]{\oplus}$
XOR is commutative, associative and self-inverse. We further have that $a\xor b=0 \Leftrightarrow a=b$ (by comparing them bit for bit).
That means
$$
a_1\xor ...\xor a_n
\\ = a_1\xor ...\xor a_{i-1}\xor a_{i+1} \xor ...\xor a_n\xor a_i
\\ = a_1\xor ...\xor a_{i-1}\xor a_{i+1} \xor ...\xor a_n\xor a_i
\\ =( a_1\xor ...\xor a_{i-1}\xor a_{i+1} \xor ...\xor a_n)\xor a_i
$$
Now if we add $a_i$, we get
$$
( a_1\xor ...\xor a_{i-1}\xor a_{i+1} \xor ...\xor a_n)\xor a_i \xor a_i
\\= 
( a_1\xor ...\xor a_{i-1}\xor a_{i+1} \xor ...\xor a_n)
$$
because $x\xor a_i\xor a_i = x$ for all $x$ because XOR is self-inverse.
Now assume $a_1\xor ...\xor a_n=c$. Then if $a_n\neq c$, we have again because XOR is self-inverse that
$$
a_1\xor ...\xor a_n=c
\\\Leftrightarrow\\
a_1\xor ...\xor a_n\xor a_n=c\xor a_n
\\\Leftrightarrow\\
a_1\xor ...\xor a_{n-1} \neq 0
$$
Inversely that means that for example for $c\xor c\xor c$ we have $c\xor c\xor c=c$, and no matter which we remove, we end up with $c\xor c=0$.
But since it was given that $n$ is even, if we had $a_1=...=a_n=c$, then $a_1\xor...\xor a_n=0$, which would be a contradiction to the requirement that at least one of the $a_i$ isn't 0.

As Zoe Allen says, the statement is false if all the $a_i$ are $0$.  We assume the problem says not all of the $a_i$ are $0$.  You are correct that removing $a_i$ from the sum gives the same result as $S XOR a_i$.  If two of the $a's$ are different, removing each of them gives a different result, so removing one of them gives a nonzero result.  If they are all the same but nonzero, $S=0$ and removing one of them gives a result that is the same as the one you removed, which we said was nonzero.

Thank you. I’m just confused on “If two of the a’s are different, removing each of them gives a different result, so removing one of them gives a nonzero result.” How can we guarantee this?

If $a_1 \neq a_2, S XOR a_1 \neq S XOR a_2$.  At least one of the XORs is nonzero
